# Severe GAE performance degradation all of sudden

Tags: performance, google-app-engine

We've seen calls start to take 10x to 100x longer as of a specific point in time (right about 2012-02-18 04:00:00).  For example, our longest call that normally can take up to 5 seconds, is now timing out at a minute. I'm pretty sure it's not a result of a code or configuration change made on our part.  All of our API calls seem to be impacted.  Using AppStats, there seems to be no glaring culprit.  (Unfortunately, I don't have a saved graph before Friday to compare to.)  We do many gets/fetches, and some writing, against the high-replication datastore -- both seem impacted.

Any insight?

Comment: Are the timeouts related to datastore operations, instance startup, just serving, or something else?

Comment: @RobertKluin It's DeadlineExceededError.  I don't have good pre-problem profile data to compare to, but seems like all RPCs are just taking longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to file a production issue so it can be investigated.

Comment: As of this afternoon, performance is back to normal.  I haven't heard back from the GAE team re what the issue was, but they were able to do something on their end to make it all better.